# Android Studio build fails, needs a full rebuild to continue

Tags: android, build, android-studio

I have a project under Git DVCS that fails to build with missing symbols on the R class every now and then, the only solucion being Build -> Rebuild project, which takes a whopping minute and a half on my ultrabook on average. Is there any solution to this slight nuisance?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Android Studio 0.1.6. Turn off External Build in Preferences > Compiler for a temporary workaround according to Google.

Comment: Reference to more official information: https://plus.google.com/116539451797396019960/posts/1XTfNjgV7hT